# PDO maxlength of an input

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have a script where the user can fill in a `textarea` and input it to the database by clicking submit.

The `textarea` has a maxlength of 500, however this can easily be removed using inspect element. How do I use PDO to check if the `textarea` has more than 500 characters?

`<textarea name="textareabox" maxlength="500"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically, the length of the inputted textarea value can be called without PDO but with simple PHP.

i.e.

```
$text = $_POST["textarea_name"];
if(strlen($text) > 500) {
    // MORE THEN 500 CHARS IN TEXTAREA
}
else {
    // LESS OR EQUAL TO 500 CHARS IN TEXTAREA SO YOU CAN POST
}
```

This would mean though that the user can post the form and you would have to show an error message, or redirect to the form or whatever, which could be considered messy. (Depending on what the use is here :) )

So you could do it with jQuery as well (javascript), and if you do not do it inline it's a lot harder for non-developers to edit this. :)

Is this good or do you need PDO for some other eason then it not being editable ? Since PHP cannot be edited by the enduser neither :)

Comment: This is fine thankyou, I wasn't aware it could be done without PDO. Thanks again!

Comment: Nooooo problemo :)